# What are the Units of Measure for the ZAREALAND & MAREALAND fields in US Census Data?

Tags: us-census

What are the Units of Measure for the ZAREALAND & MAREALAND fields in the [2010 ZCTA to Metropolitan and Micropolitan Statistical Areas Relationship File](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/docs/rel/zcta_cbsa_rel_10.txt) published by the  United States Census Bureau?

[image]

Image from the [Explanation of the 2010 ZCTA to Metropolitan and Micropolitan Statistical Areas Relationship File [PDF]](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/pdfs/rel/explanation_zcta_cbsa_rel_10.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the file is a relationship file between ZCTA and MSA, it represents the area **in square meters** that the whole ZCTA (ZAREALAND) covers, and the area that the whole MSA (MAREALAND) covers. If you notice a difference between ZAREA and ZAREALAND, or MAREA and MAREALAND, this is because there is a waterbody in that area and the *AREALAND counts only land area instead of all.

The Census Bureau uses scientific measurement units, hence meters.